# Java regular expression to get submetric from logfiles

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get submetrics from logs with thousands of lines.
Those lines are not similar so i need to match some values before get submetric.

Some simplified example lines

```
1, 2, acceptline,x,111, 100, , , 20, 20, end
1, 2, declineline,x,x, 100, 20, , end
1, 2, 3, acceptline,x,x, 1000, , 40, end
```

I try to get that numeric value which is in third comma separated column after my value match (acceptline).

In my example those values are 100 and 1000 but those can basically be any numeric value

I have succeeded to got that right submetric value with following java regular expression

```java
^.*acceptline.+?((?<submetric>,.+?){3}),.*
```

But within that regex i got submetric as `<, 100>` or what ever that numeric value is.
Now i need to improve that regex so those leading <, > is removed before accepted as submetric.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
\bacceptline(?:,[^,]*){2},\s*(\d+)
```

If the number can be a float one, use `\d*\.?\d+` instead of `\d+`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gk0XN5/1/). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `acceptline` - a word
- `(?:,[^,]*){2}` - two occurrences of a comma and then zero or more non-commas
- `,`  - a comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/QMVlXs):

```java
String string = "1, 2, acceptline,x,111, 100, , , 20, 20, end\n1, 2, declineline,x,x, 100, 20, , end\n1, 2, 3, acceptline,x,x, 1000, , 40, end";
        
String regex = "\\bacceptline(?:,[^,]*){2},\\s*(\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
// => 100 and 1000
```

Comment: I use regex101.com to try and check my regex'es. At least that tools doesn't match with that \\bacceptline(?:,[^,]*){2},\\s*(\\d+) regex.

Comment: @Rahmaputra **That** tool perfectly [finds two matches](https://regex101.com/r/gk0XN5/1/). If you have trouble with the code, that tool also [generates the code for you](https://regex101.com/r/gk0XN5/1/codegen?language=java).

Comment: I get that working, but it doesn't suit in my purpose.

Comment: @Rahmaputra No idea what your purpose is, it is out of scope.

Comment: I'm not actually coding anything, but configuring metric parser tool which use java regex. And that tool is using submetric value as label. so i need to parse that 100|1000 as submetric value.

Comment: So configure the tool you have to use Group 1 value. Something like `$1` or `\1`. In JMeter, people use `$1$`.

Comment: Example in configuration there is definition
service.metric.transaction.pattern=^.*acceptline.+?((?<submetric>,.+?){2}),.*
Parser it self is reading log line by line and matching pattern to one line at time.
After match it will forward submetric value and match string to other tool. Therefore there is also leading and ending .* in my reg ex to match whole string.
Above definition has that ,<space> in begin of submetric value.
And because that other tool uses that value as label name it may not contain any special characters, but only 3-4 digit number.

Comment: @Rahmaputra Nothing stops you from using `.*\bacceptline(?:,[^,]*){2},\s*(\d+).*`. Whatever you do already is not clear. This is not your specific tool support forum.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding regex101.com I finally got that right.

```
^.*acceptline.+?((,[^\,]*){1}),\s*(?<submetric>\d+).*
```

Thanx for Wiktor to pushing me right way with those \s and \d switches.

Comment: What you might do is accept your own answer if it solved your problem. Note that from 15 reputation points you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answers that you consider useful.